# UBRR configuration in Atmega 2560

Tags: atmega

If my rounded UBRR value is 3749, how do I assign it into both UBRRL and UBRRH? The way I think of it is UBRRL = 0xA5 and UBRRH = 0x0E

Comment: What specific AVR chip are you using?  It seems like you already know the answer, so could you clarify exactly what you are confused about or what you hope to learn by asking this question?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using avr-gcc with the standard toolchain, then you can just assign `UBRRn = 3749` (where `n` is USART's number)

Otherwise you need first write `UBRRnH`, then `UBRRnL`. Writing `UBRRnL` resets the baud rate generator, therefore `UBRRnH` has to be written before that.

3749 = 0x0EA5

```
UBRRnH = 0x0E;
UBRRnL = 0xA5;
```

Altough the number 3749 looks suspicious. Even at 16MHz and 2x mode enabled it gives you only 533 baud/sec. Are you sure the number is correct?